# How to iterate over a pandas dataframe using a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following `pandas` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['tomato', 'carrots', 'cheese'],
                              'tomato': [0.7, 0.4, 0.8],
                              'carrots': [0.15,0.3,0.1],
                               'cheese': [0.15,0.3,0.1]})

foo

source  tomato  carrots cheese
0   tomato  0.7 0.15    0.15
1   carrots 0.4 0.30    0.30
2   cheese  0.8 0.10    0.10
```

and the following list:

```
sequence = ['carrots','carrots','tomato','carrots']
```

The `sequence` describes the sequential steps: `carrots -> carrots -> tomato -> carrots`, which means going from carrots to carrots, then going from carrots to tomato and lastly going from tomato to carrots.

I would like, to iterate over `foo`, according to the above sequence, and calculate
`foo['carrots']['carrots']*foo['carrots']['tomato']*foo['tomato']['carrots']`

where `foo['carrots']['carrots']` is the element of `foo` that corresponds to `source` `carrots` and column `carrots`, so `0.3`

How could I achieve that efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create `MultiIndex Series`, then pairs from sequence, [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and get product for multiple all values:

```
s = foo.set_index('source').stack()

print (s)
source          
tomato   tomato     0.70
         carrots    0.15
         cheese     0.15
carrots  tomato     0.40
         carrots    0.30
         cheese     0.30
cheese   tomato     0.80
         carrots    0.10
         cheese     0.10
dtype: float64

sequence = ['carrots','carrots','tomato','carrots']

print (list(zip(sequence[:-1], sequence[1:])))
[('carrots', 'carrots'), ('carrots', 'tomato'), ('tomato', 'carrots')]

print (s.reindex(list(zip(sequence[:-1], sequence[1:]))))
source          
carrots  carrots    0.30
         tomato     0.40
tomato   carrots    0.15
dtype: float64


out = s.reindex(list(zip(sequence[:-1], sequence[1:]))).prod()
print (out)
0.018
```

Comment: For the record, this answer is twice as faster for a toy example of a `sequence` of length 16, and that is why it is the accepted one

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: foo = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'source': ['tomato', 'carrots', 'cheese'],
   ...:     'tomato': [0.7, 0.4, 0.8],
   ...:     'carrots': [0.15, 0.3, 0.1],
   ...:     'cheese': [0.15, 0.3, 0.1]
   ...: })
In [3]: foo
Out[3]: 
    source  tomato  carrots  cheese
0   tomato     0.7     0.15    0.15
1  carrots     0.4     0.30    0.30
2   cheese     0.8     0.10    0.10
In [4]: sequence = ['carrots', 'carrots', 'tomato', 'carrots']
   ...: product = 1
   ...: for row, col in zip(sequence[:-1], sequence[1:]):
   ...:     val = foo[foo.source == row].iloc[0][col]
   ...:     product *= val
   ...:     print(f'foo[{row}][{col}] = {val}')
   ...: 
   ...: 
foo[carrots][carrots] = 0.3
foo[carrots][tomato] = 0.4
foo[tomato][carrots] = 0.15
In [5]: product
Out[5]: 0.018
```